# quick question: alternatives to a short but a bit involved code

Tags: r

I'm trying to produce a string with the specifications (colnames and max string length of each column):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~nif, ~dni_check,
  "33333457V", "33333457",
  "44817563Q", "44817563",
  "33256164G", "33256164",
  "36050083K", "36050083"
)
df %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ str_c(" C(", max(str_length(.)), ")"))) %>%
  map2_chr(colnames(.), ., str_c) %>%
  str_c(collapse = "; ")
#> [1] "nif C(9); dni_check C(8)"
```

Just out of curiosity, would you propose an alternative, maybe in a shorter or neater way?

Comment: `paste(sprintf('%s C(%s)', names(df), sapply(Map(nchar, df), max)), collapse = '; ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `cur_column` that provides the column name and then with `sprintf` creates the `format` in the `summarise`d columns, `reduce` it to a single string with `str_c`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), 
      ~ sprintf('%s C(%d)', cur_column(), max(str_length(.))))) %>%    
   reduce(str_c, sep ='; ')
```

-output

```
#[1] "nif C(9); dni_check C(8)"
```

---

Or with `glue` create the format

```
library(glue)
df %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), 
       ~ glue('{cur_column()} C({max(str_length(.))})')))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  nif      dni_check     
#  <glue>   <glue>        
#1 nif C(9) dni_check C(8)
```

---

Or can use `imap` to paste the names and max number of characters and then `reduce` to a single string

```
library(purrr)
imap(df, ~ sprintf('%s C(%d)', .y, max(str_length(.x)))) %>%     
       reduce(str_c, sep ='; ')
```

-output

```
#[1] "nif C(9); dni_check C(8)"
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option

```
paste0(
  do.call(
    sprintf,
    c(
      fmt = "%s C(%d)",
      rev(stack(sapply(df, function(v) max(nchar(v)))))
    )
  ),
  collapse = "; "
)
```

gives

```
"nif C(9); dni_check C(8)"
```